# Use Regular Java Library in Android Project

Tags: java, android, import, libraries

I'm trying to import the standalone selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) library into my Android project. Is it possible to do that?

Can i import 3rd party java libraries to my Android Projects?

Im getting a classdefnotfound exception.

Thanks

Comment: You can add any 3rd party library you want . Can you be a bit more specific about the error or explain what you have tried ?

Comment: Make sure after adding the library you do the necessary imports in each file.(eclipse will provide the suggestions)

Comment: It would help if you could post the exception message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Some standard libraries can be used in Android and other cannot.

Why ?

Shortly : **Android API is not the java standard API !**

It is required that all standard java method used by your library exist in the Android API, otherwise you will have a runtime exception when using it (ClassNotFound or something similar).

Simple example : the whole swing api is not supported on Android (Android offer a totally different UI-API).

So posting the stacktrace to see exactly the missing class can give us a clue on the problem.